# So, when one user logs in to my application, all current users become that user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to figure out which part of my program is causing this error.

I have multiple pages that all inherit from `PageBase`. They get their user profile from `PageBase`. This is the function that gets their user name from `PageBase`:

```
uiProfile = ProfileManager.FindProfilesByUserName(CompanyHttpApplication.Current.Profile.UserName)
```

In the `CompanyHttpApplication` I have

```
    public static CompanyHttpApplication Current
    {
        get { return (CompanyHttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance; }
    }
```

and

```
    public CompanyProfileInfo Profile
    {
        get
        {
            return profile ??
                   (profile =
                    ProfileManager.FindProfilesByUserName(ProfileAuthenticationOption.Authenticated,
                                                          User.Identity.Name).Cast
                        <CompanyProfileInfo>().ToList().First());
        }
        private set { profile = value; }
    }
```

Unfortunately I did not write this section of the code and the programmer who did it is no longer on the project. Is there any one that can explain to me why, when another user logs in (while I am using the application), I become that user?

Comment: Is this a wep application..? if so you need to get Page.UserIdentity.Name.Split("\") create a string[] assign it to that

Comment: Ask the original author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Application instance is shared across every request — the application level.

You want the Session level — each user gets their own instance.

Use [`HttpContext.Current.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of [ApplicationInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpcontext.applicationinstance%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

(Code below renames original, and adds a property, to be more clear. Feel free to adjust as necessary.)

```
public static CompanyHttpApplication CurrentApplication
{
    // store application constants, active user counts, message of the day, and other things all users can see
    get { return (CompanyHttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance; }
}

public static Session CurrentSession
{
    // store information for a single user — each user gets their own instance and can *not* see other users' sessions
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question

Answer (score 5):

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance is globally shared. It is not per user. Thus, you have a shared profile that is immediately overwriting whatever you originally set when your new user logs in.

Comment: Agree +1. The op could attempt to pass User.Identity.Name for the current HttpContext rather than the HttpApplication.Current.Profile.UserName into FindProfilesByUserName

Comment: Roger. Thanks. I'm not quite sure how all this stuff works (I'm fairly new to ASP.net), but I'll make sure to get this changed up and hopefully learn more about it in the process